# How to delete last character from a string using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to delete last character from a string for instance in `123-4-` when I delete `4` it should display `123-` using **jQuery**.

Comment: You're deleting the last two characters then.

Answer (score 511, accepted):

You can also try this in plain javascript

```
"1234".slice(0,-1)
```

the negative second parameter is an offset from the last character, so you can use -2 to remove last 2 characters etc

Comment: we are (at least i am) using so much jQuery nowadays, sometimes i forget how to do in plain javascript =X

Comment: To clarify things up (as this post might be useful mostly for beginners) :  .slice() will return the result.

So one should use :  
var result = "1234".slice(0,-1);

Answer (score 43):

Why use jQuery for this?

```
str = "123-4"; 
alert(str.substring(0,str.length - 1));
```

Of course if you must:

Substr w/ jQuery:

```
//example test element
 $(document.createElement('div'))
    .addClass('test')
    .text('123-4')
    .appendTo('body');

//using substring with the jQuery function html
alert($('.test').html().substring(0,$('.test').html().length - 1));
```

Comment: str.substring(0, str.count()-1)

Comment: @GolezTrol: str.count() is not a function. str.length return number of chars in string

Comment: @ skajfes BTW this is a better example I'll edit mine above to use length

Comment: Good example with jQuery. Thanks for posting Jason. Best

Comment: Because jQuery is often easier to use and makes more sense for a lot of people.

Answer (score 10):

@skajfes and @GolezTrol provided the best methods to use.  Personally, I prefer using "slice()".  It's less code, and you don't have to know how long a string is. Just use:

```
//-----------------------------------------
// @param begin  Required. The index where 
//               to begin the extraction. 
//               1st character is at index 0
//
// @param end    Optional. Where to end the
//               extraction. If omitted, 
//               slice() selects all 
//               characters from the begin 
//               position to the end of 
//               the string.
var str = '123-4';
alert(str.slice(0, -1));
```

Comment: I prefer substring myself.  Slice for me is way too close to array slice

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with plain JavaScript:

```
alert('123-4-'.substr(0, 4)); // outputs "123-"
```

This returns the first four characters of your string (adjust `4` to suit your needs).

Comment: The slice(0, -1) solution is better because you don't need to know the string length in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This page comes first when you search on Google "remove last character jquery"

Although all previous answers are correct, somehow did not helped me to find what I wanted in a quick and easy way.

I feel something is missing. Apologies if i'm duplicating

*jQuery*

```
$('selector').each(function(){ 
  var text = $(this).html();
  text = text.substring(0, text.length-1);
  $(this).html(text);
});
```

*or*

```
$('selector').each(function(){ 
  var text = $(this).html();
  text = text.slice(0,-1);
  $(this).html(text);
})
```