# Remove a letter(:) from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have strings like Name:, Call:, Phone:....and so on in my table. I am learning jQuery and was able to access the text. My tutorial has used `trim()` to remove any whitespaces. But I want o remove ":" from the end of each string (and yes, it always lies in the end after calling `trim()` method). So how to achieve it.

Its my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $(':input[type=text], textarea').each
    (
    function ()
    {
        var newText = 'Please enter your ' +
    $(this).parent().prev().text().toLowerCase().trim();
        $(this).attr('value', newText);
    }).one('focus', function ()
    {
        this.value = '', this.className = ''
    }).addClass('Watermark').css('width', '300px');
    });
</script>
```

trim(":") did not help...

Comment: If you want to use jQuery to do it and it's always `:`, you can just slice off the last character: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308934/how-to-delete-last-character-from-a-string-using-jquery

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can replace all `:` characters:

```
var str = '::a:sd:';
str = str.replace(/:/g,''); // str = 'asd';
```

Or use a handy `rtrim()` function:

```
String.prototype.rtrim = function(character) {
    var re = new RegExp(character + '*$', 'g');
    return this.replace(re, '');
};

var str = '::a:sd:';
str = str.rtrim(':'); // str = '::a:sd';
```

Comment: replace would only replace the first instance of :

Comment: This code assumes that that last character will always a colon, which might not always be true. This doesn't trim trailing colons, it trims off any character on the end.

Comment: Still wrong. Your rtrim function doesn't take any argument so it doesn't make sense to call it with ':'. What it does is only remove space characters (\s) at the end of the string, if any.

Comment: @Shautieh: no, it still trims `:`, I just forgot to add an argument. The updated code works.

Comment: @Blender: you forgot the argument AND used \s instead in all cases, so no: it didn't "still strim :". The updated code is indeed correct, though.

Answer (score 6):

In this case just use the plain old JavaScript `replace` or `substr` methods.

You can also use a regular expression that looks for colon as the last character (the character preceding the regexp end-of-string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) "$").

```
"hi:".replace(/:$/, "")
```

> hi

```
"hi".replace(/:$/, "")
```

> hi

```
"h:i".replace(/:$/, "")
```

> h:i

This is a simplified, inline version of the `rtrim` function in Blender's answer.

EDIT: Here is a test fiddle for Blender's corrected `rtrim` function. Note that his RegExp will delete multiple occurrences of the specified character if the string ends with multiple instances of it consecutively (example bolded below).

http://jsfiddle.net/fGrPb/5/

> input = '::a:sd:' output = '::a:sd'; input = 'hi:' output = 'hi'; **input = 'hi:::' output = 'hi'**; input = 'hi' output = 'hi'; input = 'h:i' output = 'h:i'

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to remove the colon (:).

Replace one instance:

```
var with_colon = 'Stuff:';
var regex = /([^:]*):/; 
var without_colon = regex.exec(with_colon)[1];
alert(without_colon);
```

Result: `Stuff`



Replace all instances:

```
var with_colon = 'Stuff: Things:'; 
var without_colon = with_colon.replace(/([^:]*):/g,'$1'); 
alert(without_colon);
```

Result: `Stuff Things`

Answer (score 1):

To chop the last character of a string use string.slice(0,-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStr = "something:";
myStr = myStr.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This checks if the last character is a colon. If it is, the last character is removed.

```
if (str[str.length - 1] === ":") {
  str = str.slice(0, -1);
}
```

If there can be multiple trailing colons, you can replace `if` with `while`, like this:

```
while (str[str.length - 1] === ":") {
  str = str.slice(0, -1);
}
```

You could even make a generic `trim` function that accepts a string and a character and trims trailing instances of that character:

```
var trim = function(str, chr) {
  while (str[str.length - 1] === ":") {
    str = str.slice(0, -1);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a="name:";
var b=a.split(":");
alert(b[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use `lastIndexOf`

```
var str='Name:, Call:, Phone:';
var index=str.lastIndexOf(":");
alert(index);
var s=str.substring(0,index);
alert(s);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4WQs/)

Comment: This will cause a weird bug if the last character is not a colon. `lastIndexOf` will return `-1` if the character isn't found, and this could cause unwanted truncation of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`str = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(":"));`

Note that this removes everything from the last `:` to the end of the string (for example, any whitespace after the `:`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 function trim(str) {
       str = str.replace(/^:*/,"");
       return str.replace(/:*$/,"");
 }
```