# Erasing the last character (text)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying erasing the last character on the "backspace" field when I'm clicking on "button" field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="log">abcdefghijklmnop</span>
    <div class="button" id="backspace">Backspace</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            // backspace
            $( "#backspace" ).on( "click", function() {
                $('#logInfo').hide();
                $("#log").text().substr(0,this.length-1);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete last character from a string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308934/how-to-delete-last-character-from-a-string-using-jquery)

Comment: unfortunately not. I tried all those fixes but I can't adapt it with jquery :-(

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Your problem is, that you're reading the text only, you're never setting it. `.text` is a function, when any arguments is not passed, it reads the text, when an argument is passed, the is set. Pass `substr(0,this.length-1)` as an argument to `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $( "#backspace" ).on( "click", function() {
    $('#logInfo').hide();
    data = $("#log").text();
    $("#log").text(data.substr(0,data.length-1));
 });
```